# Was "Find My" removed from icloud.com?

Tags: icloud, find-my

Previously on icloud.com, "Find My" was one of the options under the dropdown to select different apps. As of today I'm no longer seeing it there. Was it removed and if so, why?

Comment: I see Find iPhone. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLwxG.png

Comment: Seems to be here as well for me: https://imgur.com/a/f4FDI0i !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find My iPhone is still present. However, Find My Friends has been removed. This brings it inline with finding *items*, which has never worked on iCloud.com

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I thought I was going crazy as I had just used it within the last week. Any reasons as to why that you may know of? I found it pretty useful from time to time.